# The driver has nor received any pakage

Tags: java, jdbc

Me pasaron un programa de un restaurante hecho en java y [access](/questions/tagged/access) - lo pasé a [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) a través de una página - al momento de querer ejecutarlo en [netbeans-8.2](/questions/tagged/netbeans-8.2), no puedo ni realizar el logueo que me muestra error...

Realicé los cambios pertinentes en las clases ConectaBD:

```java
package Base;
import java.sql.*;

public class ConectaBD {
  
  public Connection cnn;//Objeto Conexion para la BD
  public Statement stm; //clase epara conertar los objetos BD
  public ResultSet rs; //clase que manipula los datos
  
 
  String base="Restaurante";
  String usuario="root";
  String clave="root";
  
  public ConectaBD(){
      
  }
  
  public void conectar(){
    
      try{
  
          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
         String
          cadena="jdbc:mysql://database="+base+";user="+usuario+";password="+clave+";";
    
          cnn=DriverManager.getConnection(cadena);  //REALIZAMOS LA CONNEXION
          stm=cnn.createStatement(); //ACDEMOS A LOS OBJETO
  }
     catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  }
 }  
}
```

Esta es la clase Conectar:

```java
package Base;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Conectar {
    
  String base="Restaurante";
  String usuario="root";
  String clave="root";
  
  Connection conectar=null;
  
  public Connection conexion(){
  
      try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        String cadena="jdbc:mysql://localhost="+base+";user="+usuario+";password="+clave+";";
        conectar=DriverManager.getConnection(cadena);  //REALIZAMOS LA CONNEXION
 
  }
  catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  }
        return conectar;
  }   
}
```

y este es el error que me muestra al ejecutar en Netbeans - adjunto imagen: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A que se debe el error?

Comment: Por lo que veo es que no inicializas rs ni le pasas ningun parametro o le asignas un valor osea estas mandando un null.

Comment: @YeisonA en todos los formularios la única conexión que hace es la siguiente:  ConectaBD cnx = new ConectaBD();

Comment: A ver, cambia ese stm por tipo PreparedStament que es dinamico, creo que es el principal error, en todo caso te pongo una respuesta de como hacer la consulta y ya lo aplicas a tu caso, porque tienes todo muy repartido, te recomiendo ademas usar alguna arquitectura para conectar a la BD, por ejemplo MVC con DAO/DTO que es algo muy simple.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí estoy usando DAO osea que para mandar información a la BD uso objetos, pero como tu lo mandas por la información del `jtextfield` directamente solo cambia eso, te recomiendo este vídeo, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0w-2Ik-VPwU.
Es algo muy básico.

CLASE CONEXION

```
public class Conexion {

    private final String base="cinedatabase";
    private final String user="root";
    private final String password="1234";
    private final String url ="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/" + base;
    private Connection con=null;

    public Conexion() {

    }

    public Connection getConexion() {
        try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con= (Connection)DriverManager.getConnection(this.url,this.user,this.password);
        }
        catch(SQLException ex){System.err.println(ex);} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Conexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return con;

    }



}
```

ESTO ES UN **METODO** PARA REALIZAR LA CONSULTA, LA CLASE DONDE VA ESTE METODO **EXTIENDE** DE LA CLASE **CONEXION**.

```
public boolean buscarCliente(Cliente cliente) {
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Connection con = getConexion();
        String sql = "SELECT * from clientes WHERE documento=?";
        try {
            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setInt(1, cliente.getDocumento());
            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            if (rs.next()) {
                cliente.setDocumento(Integer.valueOf(rs.getString("documento")));
                cliente.setNombre(rs.getString("nombre"));
                cliente.setApellido(rs.getString("apellido"));
                cliente.setSexo(rs.getString("sexo"));
                return true;
            }
            System.err.println("No existe ningun registro con ese número de documento");
            return false;

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
            return false;

        } finally {
            try {
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                System.err.println(ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente pude ejecutar el programa...

En ambas clases tuve que modificar la siguiente línea de acuerdo a la versión del conector entre Java y MySQL (el proyecto trae *mysql-conector-java-5.1.24-bin.jar*):

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
```

y los catch de ambas clases también las modifiqué:

```
 catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
```

}

y anduvo el proyecto!!!!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]